# Ubuntu 16.04 desktop won't start after preseed automated installation

Tags: system-installation, 16.04, gui, preseed, ubiquity

My ubuntu xenial doesn't want to start. Here what I see right after the BIOS:

[image: After the Bios]

All preseed that I have tried: [From help ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt)

I've tried to install with those preseeds with some different intel NUC (+ Virtual Machines) and both are not working.

I have my own preseed file which is working with 15.10 desktop. Do you know what have been changed in this release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and found that the problem was in LVM. In my preseed.cfg I have:

`d-i partman-auto/method string lvm`

My preseed works without problems in a Ubuntu Server iso but when I use a LiveCD version something goes wrong. If I change the method to *regular* the problem disappears

`d-i partman-auto/method string regular`